# L'expression « un fossé qui se creuse »

Tags: sens, expressions

Que veut dire cette phrase ? J’imagine que c’est quand quelque chose devient de pire en pire non ?

Comment: Warning, groaner alert: Pas toujours négative cette phrase car comme un livre qui s’écrit lui-même doit être un plus pour les écrivains, les terrassiers doivent apprécier un fossé qui se creuse, non?

Answer (score 3):

De manière générale, c'est la combinaison entre la notion d'*écart important* (le *fossé*), lié à une *augmentation* (*qui se creuse*).

> Une différence qui s'accentue.
>
> Un désaccord, qui augmente.
>
> Une inégalité (salaire, soins, ...), qui empire.
>
> Un éloignement (entre personnes, entreprises, états), qui augmente sur certains sujets (économie, politique, ...).

Comment: Cela implique également qu'il y avait déjà un fossé (un écart notable), et qu'il devient plus grand.

Answer (score 1):

Cela ne signifie pas forcement de pire en pire, ça indique plutôt qu'un désaccord entre deux personnes va en s'accroissant, devient irréconciliable.

Comment: Le sens n'est pas limité aux désacords. Si je devais donner un cas typique je parlerais d'inégalités, de valeurs ou de biens, voire même autres qu'au sens humain.